# JavaScript get day numbers of the month as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, typescript

Hello guys how is it possible get the day numbers till today and write them in an array :
the result should be look like:

```
daysNum = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14'];
```

Comment: What does _"get the day numbers till today"_ mean? --- Can you add your efforts? (see [mcve])

Comment: so.. what you want is to go from 1 to nr-1 and push all the values into an array?

Comment: Follow this link for sample code https://jsfiddle.net/jzwouppu/1/

Comment: thx guys Nenad Vracar solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get date date with `new Date()` and `getDate()` and then use `Array.from()` to create array with all previous days.

```js
var days = Array.from(Array((new Date).getDate()), (e, i) => i + 1)
console.log(days)
```

Another option is to use spread syntax with `map()` instead of `Array.from()`

```js
var days = [...Array((new Date).getDate())].map((e, i) => i + 1)
console.log(days)
```

Comment: ist it possible to wrap the numbers in ' ' quotes ?

Comment: Sure but then its a string not a number  https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1698/

Answer (score 3):

```js
array=[]  
len=new Date().getDate();
for(i=1;i<=len;i++){
    array.push(i);
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try including this script.

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
arr = [];
today.getDate();
for (i = 1; i<=today.getDate();i++)
{
    arr.push(i);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var days =[];
for(var i = 0; i < day; i++ )
{
    days[i] = i+1;
  console.log(days[i]);
}
console.log(days.toString());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zt3jhchn/

Returns `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14`